# How does the declaration of a QML "constructor" really work?

Tags: qt, qml

I can declare a constructor for my QML object using `Component.onCompleted`:

MyObject.qml

---

```
Item {
   Rectangle: {
      id: something_in_my_object
      color: "white"
      anchors.fill: parent
   }

   Component.onCompleted: {
      console.log("a MyObject has been constructed")
   }
}
```

---

... but I don't really understand how this works.   How is it that I am allowed to name something in my inheritance tree (`Component`) and define a handler for its `onCompleted` signal like that?

I don't think I can do that for any other arbitrary signal in the inheritance tree, can I?

(In fact, I'm not even completely sure that Component is an object in the inheritance tree ... I just can't see how else an Item "has" a Component?)

Comment: You can read about attached signals here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers

Comment: It isn't constructor, it's just a way to handle a moment when object creation is finished. And as mentioned before - it has "strange" name because of its nature (attached signal).